# Android: Render a string in an imageview

Tags: android

is there a way to render a string resource (from `strings.xml`) in an ImageView?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that?  Would it be easier to put an TextView over an ImageView in a FrameLayout instead?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of a FrameLayout. It works.

What I want to achieve: I have an Imageview, which is blank in the beginning. There should be a text "Click to add an image" to clarify that a user can select an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to create an image to initialize the image view.  The image itself could contain the text.  If this is undesirable for whatever reason, you can simply use a relative layout to position a TextView above the ImageView and then show or hide it appropriately.